# How can I change width of "output profile" toolbox in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: texniccenter

After installing TeXnicCenter 2.0 on Windows 10, in the toolbar the width of the Output Profile box, i.e., where it says LaTeX => DVI etc. is so small, that I can only see LateX =>, which is quite useless. How on Earth do I change that? I tried everything what a simple windows user could think of. My resolution is 3840 x 2160.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Your only choice here might be to change the font size used by the editor. Try under Tools > Options > Text Format > Font.

Comment: What is the resolution of your screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on `Tools` and then select `Customize...`. Then click on the output profile box (a black rectangle will appear), and then drag it with your mouse to the desired width.

[image]